# how to make ajax call in div without button click javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I would like to know how to make ajax call in div without button click in javascript

Also, I will pass corresponding id to the ajax function in javascript

```js
function handleCall(pr_id) {
  var li = $.ajax({
    url: "/en/send-money-from-" + sourcecn + "-to-" + targetcn,
    method: 'get',
    global: false,
    async: false,
    data: {
      idvalue: pr_id
    },
    success: function(value) {
      return value;
    }
  }).responseText;
  console.log(JSON.parse(li));
}

render() {
  <div id="trans" onload=${()=>this.handleCall(this.id)}> // not working
    <p>Cal the ajax function without click button and pass id to ajax function</p>
  </div>
}
```

Comment: Are you using `react`?

Comment: Just put the `$.ajax()` call directly in a document.ready event handler and it will be called on load. You will need to change two things in your code, though. Firstly how you read pr_id` an secondly remove `async: false` as it's incredibly bad practice. Research how to work with callbacks properly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava am using lit-element

Comment: use setinterval, unless you had some other event in mind.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks for reply, wil try, if you already familiar please share sample, thanks much

Comment: I would if I could. All you need to do is copy+paste what you have in to a document.ready handler - which you should already have if you're using jQuery. I can't help you retrieve `pr_id` as you've not specified what value you're expecting it to have when you run this function without the context of an element

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks, `pr_id` is div `id` which is passed the to ajax call,

Comment: Yes, but if you're running this immediately on load there is no way to know which `div` should be used. Unless you mean there is only ever one div..?

Comment: What exactly does your `this` refer to here? It's either the `div` or the `Window`

Comment: @AmitDas refers to `div`

Comment: @Senthil. Then how come you are accessing `this.handleCall`? As far as I can see, you `handleCall` is not a property of the `div`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan my scenario is I have static data in div, once `div` loaded i need to make ajax call,  but donknow how to make ajax call without button click, which event to use

Comment: @AmitDas I got stuck how to access the function `handlecall` without button click and also pass `id`

Comment: @Senthil, not sure but try this:
`onload=${e=>handleCall(e.target.id)}`
Since I'm not familiar with the framework you are using, it's really hard to understand the context of `this` here.